# Best way to iterate through a Matrix of coordinates in MATLAB?

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, loops, coordinates

I am attempting to translate the C++ code given [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain)  to MATLAB:

```
// Implementation of Andrew's monotone chain 2D convex hull algorithm.
// Asymptotic complexity: O(n log n).
// Practical performance: 0.5-1.0 seconds for n=1000000 on a 1GHz machine.
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef int coord_t;         // coordinate type
typedef long long coord2_t;  // must be big enough to hold 2*max(|coordinate|)^2

struct Point {
    coord_t x, y;

    bool operator <(const Point &p) const {
        return x < p.x || (x == p.x && y < p.y);
    }
};

// 2D cross product of OA and OB vectors, i.e. z-component of their 3D cross product.
// Returns a positive value, if OAB makes a counter-clockwise turn,
// negative for clockwise turn, and zero if the points are collinear.
coord2_t cross(const Point &O, const Point &A, const Point &B)
{
    return (A.x - O.x) * (B.y - O.y) - (A.y - O.y) * (B.x - O.x);
}

// Returns a list of points on the convex hull in counter-clockwise order.
// Note: the last point in the returned list is the same as the first one.
vector<Point> convex_hull(vector<Point> P)
{
    int n = P.size(), k = 0;
    vector<Point> H(2*n);

    // Sort points lexicographically
    sort(P.begin(), P.end());

    // Build lower hull
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (k >= 2 && cross(H[k-2], H[k-1], P[i]) <= 0) k--;
        H[k++] = P[i];
    }

    // Build upper hull
    for (int i = n-2, t = k+1; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (k >= t && cross(H[k-2], H[k-1], P[i]) <= 0) k--;
        H[k++] = P[i];
    }

    H.resize(k);
    return H;
}
```

I am having some trouble because in the C++ program, iterating through the points is easier. I wish to do the same in MATLAB but want to do that taking one **point (both x and y coordinates)** at a time instead of one particular value at a given index at a time.

To generate the matrix of coordinates I am using the following as of now -

```
x = randi(1000,100,1);
y = randi(1000,100,1);
points = [x,y];
```

Answer (score 1):

Iteration is often unnecessary in Matlab.  Given your vectors `x` and `y` I think that the C++ code translates to

```
convhull(x,y)
```

in Matlab.  No (programmer-written) iteration, not much else either.

Comment: +1: that's what you pay for; to not have to re-invent these kinds of wheels :)

Comment: Thank you. The purpose of converting this code is not because I want to see what happens. 
The purpose is to - 

1. Learn different aspects of MATLAB programming by taking up application based examples.
2. Get better at programming by being able to "think better"

I understand asking on stackoverflow for this isn't the best way, but it does help to get started by asking around.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a matrix C columns by 2 rows M, you just do. (where row1 =x and row2 = y)

```
M=[x;y]
FOR point = drange(M)
    //code
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post slightly. Does your answer hold for that? Also, I am not clear on what you mean by "matrix C columns by 2 rows M"

Comment: I am yet to try this. Will try it soon enough and update here. Thanks again.